# C# Inheriting a User Control that has variable set at runtime

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, inheritance, reference

I have a main form that acts as a "Wizard" for a bunch of different user controls. I have one user control with relatively basic operations, and I am trying to create a new user control that inherits this basic user control.

However, the base user control has a variable containing the main form (so the user control can access the wizard control functions in the main form). When I create a new "inherited user control" the Designer complains that the reference to the main for has not been set to an instance of the object. I set the reference to the MainForm during runtime when I create an instance of the base user control.

Is there a way to make this work? Below is some simplified code demonstrating my problem.

MainForm.cs:

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public string exampleString = "From MainForm";

    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BaseControl base = new BaseControl();
        base.mainForm = this;
    {

}
```

BaseControl.cs

```
public partial class BaseControl : UserControl
{
    public MainForm mainForm { get; set;}

    public TestPanel()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        string needed = mainForm.exampleString;    //Object reference not set to an instance of an object here
    }
}
```

So when I try to create a user control that inherits BaseControl through `Solution -> Add -> New Item -> Inherited User Control` and select BaseClass, the designer complains of the "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error at the `string needed = mainForm.exampleString` line in BaseControl.cs.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated. Hopefully this is enough information for you to understand what I am trying to do.

Thanks.

Comment: `I set the reference ... when I create an instance`  Not quite.  You create a `new` instance, then in the *next* line, you set the reference.  I would rethink this whole thing and rather than a form reference, embed the "Wizard" functions into the UserControl perhaps via a Wizard object passed **in the constructor** so that you *do*  'set the reference you create an instance'

Comment: Could you rename variable `base` to `bc` or something else

Comment: Your *Wizard* could implement a known Interface. When you *inject* your User Control with an instance of the *Wizard*, the UC will have means to call known public methods and subscribe to the public events of the *Wizard*, through the Interface. This way, you don't have hard-coded references to specific class names, just the Interface.

Answer (score 1):

The code which you shared will not work, neither at run-time nor in design-time.

You are trying to use `mainForm.exampleString` in constructor of `BaseControl` while `mainForm` will be assigned just after creating an instance of `BaseControl`.

In such cases, specially when you want to have design-time support, you can derive from [`ISupportInitialize`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.isupportinitialize?view=netframework-4.7.2) interface and override `BeginInit` and `EndInit`.

**Example**

The following control implements `ISupportInitialize`. If you drop an instance of the control on the form, at run-time, it tries to find the parent form and if it was `MainForm` tries to use public members of the `MainForm`:

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Forms;
public class MyControl : Control, ISupportInitialize
{
    public void BeginInit()
    {
    }

    public void EndInit()
    {
        var parent = this.FindForm() as MainForm;
        if (parent != null)
        {
            //Access to MainForm members
        }
    }
}
```

This is just an example that shows how to use `ISupportInitialize`. In action, it's not a good idea to have a dependency to a specific type of parent form. A better idea as already mentioned in Jimi's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54372353/c-sharp-inheriting-a-user-control-that-has-variable-set-at-runtime/54376559#comment95561716_54372353) is relying on interfaces. For example you can have a property of `ISomeInterface` in your control. The interface should contain the methods or properties which you want to have for the parent of your control. Then implement the interface in some forms. Then after you dropped an instance of your control at run-time or design-time, assign the form to the property.

Comment: Let me know if you have any question about the answer.